# How do I declare an attribute that takes either undef or a role?

Tags: perl, roles, moose

I have a Moose class with an attribute that does a certain role:

```
has foo => (is => 'rw', does => 'Foo::Bar');
```

Now how do I change the declaration to allow for `undef`? I tried `does => 'Maybe[Foo::Bar]'`, but that does not seem to work, not letting legitimate defined values through.

Comment: What version of Moose are you using? `does => 'Maybe[MyRole]'` works for me (Moose 2.0201).

Comment: Indeed, simplified code sample also works for me (2.0202). Off to check for code errors, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to specify such constraint with `isa`. According to [Moose::Util::TypeConstraints](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose%3a%3aUtil%3a%3aTypeConstraints) role name is also valid option.

```
package Foo::Bar;
use Moose::Role;


package WithFooBar;
use Moose;
with 'Foo::Bar';


package Thing;
use Moose;

has foo => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Maybe[Foo::Bar]');

package main;
use Test::More;

ok(Thing->new(foo => undef));               # pass
ok(Thing->new(foo => WithFooBar->new));     # pass
ok(Thing->new(foo => Thing->new));          # fails

done_testing;
```